# How to group elements inside <g> tag in joint.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, jointjs

How to group svg elements like rect , text inside g tag in joint.js using custom elements?

I just need something like this.

```
 <g record-group="0" joint-selector="group_0" id="v-225" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,10,30)">
<g joint-selector="bodiesGroup_0" id="v-222" fill="transparent" stroke="none">
<rect x="-10" y="0" height="20" item-id="value_1" joint-selector="itemBody_value_1" id="v-217" class="record-item-body" stroke="black" width="83"></rect>
</g>
</g>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create nested markup using the `children` property:

```
var Circle = joint.dia.Element.define('custom.Circle', {
    markup: [{
        tagName: 'g',
        selector: 'wrapper',
        children: [{
            tagName: 'text'
        }]
    }]
});
```